# My scroll-wheel is going haywire

Tags: windows-10, mouse, freeze, scrolling

When I try to scroll my mouse-wheel down-wards, it has an almost systematic way of bugging out on me. First it scrolls the amount you'd expect, then it scrolls down and up the same distance, then it scrolls back up once, then it scrolls 3 down, then 1-2 up etc etc. If I try to scroll up, it almost always scrolls down the same distance.

From time to time the scroll-wheel will freeze on a window, and stop scrolling there forever, I can however bring the mouse to a different window and scroll just fine. If I click the middle-mouse-button I can scroll using the drag-able scroller for some time, until that freezes (it does not bounce around though) and then I can go back to scrolling with the scroll-wheel. To get to the bottom of a page, sometimes I have to switch between these two modes of scrolling multiple times.

The issue occours everywhere: In games, in any browser I have tested, in Windows Settings and anywhere you would expect to scroll, really. The issue started happening about 1 year and 3 months after building the PC.

**Things I have tried:**

- Cleaning the mouse
- Reinstalling drivers
- Reinstalling Windows 10
- Hooking up a different mouse (I use a Razer Naga, I hooked a Dell Office mouse up to it, same result)
- Using the mouse on an office (Dell) PC, no issues
- Running the PC in safe-boot, same issue
- Checking for conflicting software, didn't seem to have any neither before or after reinstallation
- Using a different USB-port

**Specs:**

- Windows 10
- Razer Naga Epic Chroma (and Dell mouse)
- custom-made pc (if a detailed list of hardware would help, one will be given to the best of my memory)

I hope someone has experienced the same and/or knows of ways to fix it. Please let me know if there is any information that will help solving this.

Comment: This sounds like some sort of low level problem within the PC itself. I don't know how to log USB activity, but that's what I'd want to do. Most PCs have more than one internal hub and internal devices like webcams hooked up to them. Maybe something else connected is putting "noise" into your mouse data stream. On Linux (which I use), there are system logs which would normally show errors when things like this happen. I'm sure Windows has something similar if you know where to look.